# sudo, su, -c, "$pw" - using them all together

Tags: linux, sudo, su

I need to run a command under su and sudo at the same time and redirect the output.

To do it manually the command I use is:

```
sudo su - user1
```

and then run the command I need from the prompt.

I've worked out the syntax to pipe the command I need into su:

```
su - user1 -c "more .ssh/authorized_keys" > scratch/output.txt
```

...but don't know how to get the sudo in as well.

I was hoping I could type something like:

```
sudo su - user1 -c "more .ssh/authorized_keys" > scratch/output.txt
```

...and then getting really clever do something like:

```
echo "$pw" | sudo su - user1 -c "more .ssh/authorized_keys" > scratch/output.txt
```

...to pipe in the password as well.

I've only been using Linux for a few weeks (I'm a VB programmer normally).

Thanks

Kristian

Comment: What is wrong, it prints error, it doesnt work properly?  Third works for me

Comment: if the `$pw` is the password of the user `user1`, I don't think this will works.

Comment: Corrected 3rd one as forgot sudo command. Error when running 2nd one after entering password is: Sorry, MyLogin is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - user1 -c more .ssh/authorized_keys as root on wksta44.company.co.uk

Comment: @MicroAleX - I was hoping "$pw" would be my password as that is what is asked for if I don't try to pipe in the password - Just su asks for user1 password, sudo takes your password (I think).

Comment: @Kristian have you tried `echo PASSWORD | sudo -u user1 -S more .ssh/authorized_keys | tee scratch/output.txt` ?

Comment: @dave. With this command: echo 'pa$$word' | sudo -u user1 -S more .ssh/authorized_keys | tee /scratch/output.txt. Error text is: 
tee: /scratch/output.txt: No such file or directory
[sudo] password for userKris: Sorry, user userKris is not allowed to execute '/bin/more .ssh/authorized_keys' as user1 on wksta44.company.co.uk.

Comment: @Kristian for the first message `tee: no such file...`, use `tee scratch/output.txt` instead of `tee /scratch/output.txt` (my typo, sorry). I suggest you to use absolute paths to avoid confusion. The second message says that you're not allowed to run the command `more` through `sudo`. Are you sure to have the permissions to run `sudo`?

Comment: @Dave. I don't know User1's password and so I think I need to use sudo and su together for some reason. As per my post I can run sudo su - user1 without any problems, but once I get this working I then need to run this command on 20 different machines to find which command is being run via the key. Thanks